# How do I use a class parents and children?

Tags: c#, object, parent

I have a Object called Person and I need to have values decided by other classes or objects, one of them will be whether the Object person is a boy or girl and the two classes will give back variables like average body weight for example.
How do i accomplish this?

Comment: Is this your home work?

Comment: Ask those `boys` and `girls` about their respective body weights and then divide it with number of persons you asked. It will get you the average.

Comment: Thats not what I'm looking for, i need to know how to use other objects or classes for resource or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your "Person" a couple attributes

either `bool isBoy` or `string(Enum?) Gender`

as well as `float bodyWeight` or similar.

Then you need to make a `list` of Person, and get the `Average` of each persons `bodyWeight`

you can also search through this list to find `where` the person `isBoy` or `gender` matches `boy` or `girl`